# Other alternatives of Objective-C

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios4

I have already learned Objective-C to develop iPhone apps. But since I lost my Mac notebook, I have to use my other windows laptop. I still want to develop iPhone apps!

What do you recommend to do:

- Should I install Mac OS X on a virtual machine?
- Should I install Mac OS X as a secondary operating system (dual boot)
- Do you recommend me using a Windows iPhone SDK? If yes then which one?
  Airplay? Dragonfire?

I am interested in knowing if airplay or dragonfire will allow me to have control over the iPhone just as the iPhone SDK does? Or are they limited on functionality?

Comment: Did somebody just discover the backtick? ;)

Comment: why the close! isn't this programming related?!! common guys! what is a back tick?

Comment: For the record: Jonathan Grynspan refers to the first edit by Kiril Kirov where almost every second word was surrounded by a backtick. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6206253/2

Comment: i don't know how that happened! was this the reason it was closed??!

Comment: No, it was closed because it isn't really a programming question. A question like "how do I use AES encryption on iOS?" or "app crashes when I use `System.UInt64`" is a programming question. Yours isn't quite so relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Try [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) to develop iPhone Apps using .Net or use [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) and develop with JavaScript.

Comment: they both require a mac and iphone sdk installed!!

Comment: you're right. I read the question more like alternatives to the language than alternatives to a mac.

Comment: Because that's what the title says and the post is unclear.